# Задача из книги "A byte of Python", сделать адресную книгу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здорова всем. Начал делать задачу из книги и не понять почему когда пытаюсь после удаления контакта у меня возвращает searching, и даже после 2-х контактов всё равно возвращает searching. В чём же моя ошибка? Просто хотя бы подскажите на что обратить внимание?

```
import pickle


class Address:
    # Имя файла в котором будет сохранён объект.
    library = 'Book.data'
    ab = {}

    # Запись в файл.
    f = open(library, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(ab, f)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
    f.close()

    del ab  # Удаляем переменную ab.

    # Считываем из хранилища.
    f = open(library, 'rb')
    stored = pickle.load(f)  # Загружаем объект из файла.
    print(stored)
    f.close()

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def append(self):
        self.name = input('Введите имя: ')
        self.email = input('Введите адрес: ')
        Address.stored[self.name] = self.email
        if self.name in Address.stored:
            print('\nАдрес:', Address.stored)

    def delete(self):
        self.name = input('Введите имя для удаления: ')
        del Address.stored[self.name]
        print('\nВ адресной книге: {0} 
                   контактов\n'.format(len(Address.stored)))
        for name, address in Address.stored.items():
            print('\nКонтакт: {0}, с адресом {1}.'.format(name, address))


r = Address('Воронин', 'voron@mail.ru')
running = True
while running:
    searching = int(input('Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3- 
                           Изменить; 4-Найти": '))
    if searching == 1:
        r.append()

    if len(Address.stored) > 1:
        running = False


run = True
while run:
    search = int(input('Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3- 
                     Изменить; 4-Найти": '))
    if search == 2:
        r.delete()

    if len(Address.stored) == 0:
        run = False
```

Вот вывод:

```
{}
Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3-Изменить; 4-Найти": 1
Введите имя: serg
Введите адрес: aerg

Адрес: {'serg': 'aerg'}
Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3-Изменить; 4-Найти": 1
Введите имя: aerg
Введите адрес: aerg

Адрес: {'serg': 'aerg', 'aerg': 'aerg'}
Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3-Изменить; 4-Найти": 1
Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3-Изменить; 4-Найти": 2
Введите имя для удаления: serg

В  адресной книге: 1 контактов


Контакт: aerg, с адресом aerg.
Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3-Изменить; 4-Найти": 1
Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3-Изменить; 4-Найти": 2
Введите имя для удаления: aerg

В адресной книге: 0 контактов


Process finished with exit code 0`
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ваша программа работала нормально, обработка ВСЕХ опций должна быть в одном цикле.
То есть должен быть один цикл while примерно такой:

```
run = True
while run:
    search = int(input('Выберите вариант: "1-добавить; 2-удалить; 3- 
                        Изменить; 4-Найти": '))

    if search == 1:
        r.append()

    if search == 2:
        r.delete()

    if search == 3:
        # Код для изменения записи

    if search == 4:
        #Код для поиска записи

    if len(Address.stored) == 0:
        run = False
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Ответ чуть позже напишу.

Comment: Да всё правильно, выход происходит. Но я помню что так уже писал, но у меня не получалось, только почему к сожалению не помню.